# RabbitMQ 3.12 - Unexpected Channel shutdown ERROR with NACKS RECEIVED message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We recently upgraded our RabbitMQ cluster to RabbitMQ 3.12. After setting up the new environment, we started getting the error log for "Shutdown Signal". Some examples of logged errors.

> 2024-02-08 07:41:26.339 [Catalina-utility-4] INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: connectionFactory#3c1b8bd2:0/SimpleConnection@55bc2132 [delegate=amqp://webapp@XXX.80.32.XXX:5672/, localPort= 39050] 2024-02-08 07:49:12. 946 [api@thread-pool-rabbitmq-connection@thread-2] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - shutdown signal: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=NACKS RECEIVED, class-id=0, method-id=0) 2024-02-08 07:49:13.048 [api@thread-pool-rabbitmq-connection@thread-8] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Shutdown Signal: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=NACKS RECEIVED, class-id=0, method-id=0)

Before updating the rabbitMQ version (old version RabbitMQ 3.8.27) there were no logged errors of this kind. We use the same spring boot application to access both cluster environments. We are using spring boot 2.7.18.

Do you have any suggestion regarding root cause and solution in our spring application?
Thanks in advance. Ramazan